# GCP - DLP - Regex

Tags: regex, google-cloud-dlp

Trying to process a BigQuery table with a custom infotype of RegEx variety.

RegEx I am using: `^(\d{5})$`

In table below, I am trying to tag only against the "*Codes*" which are 5 digits. With the above RegEx, there are 0 matches.

With the following RegEx: `\d{5}`

It matches against **all** instances of 5 digits (including the two in Other)

How do I get it so that it only matches against 5 digits at the start of a "*cell*"(?) and ending with the 5th digit? Thanks a lot, been bogged down by this.

```
Name | Other     | Code
Blah | Test12345 | 12345
Bleh | 54311Test | 54311
```

Comment: `^(\d{5})$` should definitely do the work - can you please share the code so we can help

Comment: Paul, could you tell us what is the query returning 0 matches? I reproduced it and it just seems to be working fine... Can you update with a most reproducible case (code and sample dataset)?

Comment: Thanks Mikhail / Sergi - the solution adding word boundaries seems to have worked (minus a few cases.) this is running the regex off the DLP API not locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following RegEx:

```
\b\d{5}\b
```

Comment: Thanks Marko - this seems to have worked for the most part but I'm running into an issue now with a particular regex: \b[A-Za-z0-9]{7}\b, this turns up 0 results against columns with 7 alphanumeric characters... if I remove the word boundaries, it starts matching against more but misses a lot of cells with 7 alphanumerics (eg a 100 row column with all 7 alphanumeric characters and it only matched 5 rows...) another bug?

Answer (score 0):

Your first instinct of using `^(\d{5})$` should have worked, but did not work because of a bug within the custom regex feature.

The Cloud DLP API team is aware of this issue and they are working on a fix.

Update: Bug has been fixed so this works now. Using `\b(regex)\b` works as well.

Comment: Thanks Mike - I responded with Marko with another potential bug, not sure if syntax related or something related to API

Comment: Sorry about the delay. It is working now. I put together a sample call in the [API reference docs page](https://justpaste.it/41yx8). I had to change your test data a bit to match on `[A-Za-z0-9]{7}`.